# Remove Item from Linked List

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, nodes, removeclass

I have added comments to explain my logic

```
public void removeStrin(String name) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    // If the name is equal to null throw an exception
    if(name == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    //set the removeTempString to the head
    Game Rem = head;
```

Comment: Where is the linked list? Is it a linked list of games? Or is the game class itself representing a linked list? You might want to show the game class too... Other than that, usually what you have to do is change the pointer from prev to next and then delete current... And yes. Going into a recursion is wrong. Also, where in the loop are you going to the next element?

Comment: It is a linked list of games.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this, set the `previous.nxt = nodetobedeleted.next;`
and empty and resources the notobedeleted might have.

```
        public void removeGame(String name) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            // If the name is equal to null throw an exception
            if(name == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }

            //set the removeTempString to the head
            Game removeTempString = head;
            Game prev = null;
            //while it is not null
            while(removeTempString != null) {
                //if the removeTempString.name equals the String name
                if(removeTempString.name.equals(name)){
                     if(prev != null){
                          prev.next  = removeTempString.next;
                     }
                }
                // set prev to current`enter code here`
                prev = removeTempString;
                // to iterate set it to next node in list
                removeTempString = removeTempString.next;//the next pointer you have

    }
```

Comment: check the code. its already there  `if(prev != null){
                          prev.next  = removeTempString.next;
                     }`

Comment: yeah. I don't think that call is needed. it might lead to never ending recursion. Feel free to modify the method. It was just a sample code.

Comment: you can even use equalsIgnoreCase if you want case insensitive comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Summatively, your problem calls for finding and removing a node in linked list irrespective of its position in chain, wherefore, it could be the first one, last one or somewhere in the middle.

Provided underneath are some safe assumption(s) regarding the problem.

1. The **Game** class has the following structure.

   ```
    class Game{
     public String name;
     public Game prev;
     public Game next;
    }
   ```
2. The **head**  object is already defined in the containing class.

The **removeGame()** method must be coded in the following three set of scenarios which will take care of node deletions implicitly. If it returns something, you can get infos on successful deletions. Here it returns boolean. Its actually based on the theme that the subject node which needs to be deleted must be made a candidate of garbage collection.

```
public boolean removeGame(Game txt)
{
if(txt==null)return false;
Game itr = head;

//if its header
if(itr.name.equals(txt.name))
{
Game newHead = head.next;
head=newHead;
//The previous header hence gets derefrenced and becomes a candidate of garbage collection
return true;
}

//if its midway or end
itr = head.next;
while(itr!=null){
Game subjectNode = itr;
if(subjectNode.name.equals(txt.name))
 {
 Game newPrev = subjectNode.prev;
 Game newNext = subjectNode.next;
 newPrev.next = subjectNode.next;
 newNext.prev= subjectNode.prev;

 subjectNode=null;
//This makes it derefrenced and hence subject to garbage collections after refrence swaps.
     return true;
     }
    itr = itr.next;
     }
    return false;
     }
```

Also, since you are doing java implementation, prefer fitting your scenario using **LinkedList** class of java's util package.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this logic, it applies both ways

```
public Object delete(Object key) // works
{
    Node prev = null;
    Node curr = top;
    Object result = null;

    //search for the key
    while((curr != null) && (!curr.getData().equals(key)))
    {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr.getNext();
    }

    //found the item we are looking for!
    if ( curr != null )
    {
        //wait! is the item we are looking for the first element in the list?
        if ( prev != null )//nah, it's not 
        {
            prev.setNext(curr.getNext());
        }else //yes! it is 
        {
            top = curr.getNext();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```